# TexShop and pdflatexmk: "env: perl: No such file or directory "

Tags: installing, mactex, texshop

on my (almost) freshly installed Mac with MacTex my TexShop cannot run the *mk scripts because of this error:

```
"env: perl: No such file or directory "
```

This is obviously a configuration issue with TexShop and perl (and shouldn't be to hard) but I can't seem to figure it out.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXShop is not involved in this. The `latexmk` script starts with the shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

that tells the operating system to use Perl for interpreting the script. The error message says that no `perl` executable is found. Since TeXShop only prepends `/usr/texbin` to the PATH environment variable, this means either that your PATH variable is malformed or that no `perl` executable is installed on your system (which is dubious, as Mac OS X has it by default).

You should check what's the answer to the command

```
echo $PATH
```

issued to the Terminal.

Comment: Thank you, that my well be true since I fiddled with the PATH recently. Tomorrow I'll try to fix it, then approve your answer / comment again.

Comment: @albifant The standard version of Perl is in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: This is correct. Your answer made it clear to me that my $PATH was corrupted. Thanks, it kept messing with a lot of things lately. For the fun of it, take a look at this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44055/delete-things-from-path